# Open JDK latest Javax mail not sent

Tags: java, security, ssl, mail-server

Upgraded to `JDK 11.0.16` and the emails server is failing to send emails.
before that on `JDK 11.0.6`, emails were working fine.

I checked my config 100 times, but getting to know JDK from 11.0.11 disabled the `TLSv1`, `TLSv1.1` support

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/67141849d922a3899fcb4429a520b874b7d91b4c/src/java.base/share/conf/security/java.security#L736

What could be the possible solutions to fix this, so that my application keep sending an email!

Answer (score 1):

The possible solutions could be

## Solution1.

Edit the `java.security` file and remove the `TLSv1`, `TLSv1.1` from `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`

location of java security file is
`usr/local/openjdk-11/conf/security/java.security`

## Solution 2.

The Second solution could be forcing your Mail implementation to use TLSv1.2 like this

```
    // add this line mail.smtp.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2; in properties
    // in your Mail Implementation class
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols","TLSv1.2");
```

or your Java Mail impl will look like this

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2"); // New Line
prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", mailUri.getHost());
mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(prop);
```

These solutions should help :)